# Symfony 4.4: Cannot autowire service "Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextFactory"

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I am upgrading from framework version 3 to 4.4 of symfony. I've got the base running. But my automated tests are failing as the framework itself is missing type hinting on an certain file requiring an translator interface.

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException: Cannot autowire service "Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextFactory": argument "$translator" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.

/srv/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php:54
/srv/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/AbstractRecursivePass.php:83
/srv/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php:32
/srv/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/AbstractRecursivePass.php:47
/srv/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/Compiler.php:94
/srv/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php:762
/srv/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:594
/srv/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:136
/srv/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:79
/srv/tests/BaseTestCase.php:32
```

The file causing this error.

```
    /**
     * Creates a new context factory.
     *
     * @param TranslatorInterface $translator        The translator
     * @param string|null         $translationDomain The translation domain to
     *                                               use for translating
     *                                               violation messages
     */
    public function __construct($translator, string $translationDomain = null)
    {
        if (!$translator instanceof LegacyTranslatorInterface && !$translator instanceof TranslatorInterface) {
            throw new \TypeError(sprintf('Argument 1 passed to "%s()" must be an instance of "%s", "%s" given.', __METHOD__, TranslatorInterface::class, \is_object($translator) ? \get_class($translator) : \gettype($translator)));
        }

        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->translationDomain = $translationDomain;
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this to not load or how I should fix it. I've tried updating composer and most versions to the newest supported by symfony 4.4.

It's not a file inside my project that is requiring this type hinting. It is a framework file.

Comment: There really should not be any reason to autowire this service.  It's only application services that are normally autowired.  The only thing I can think of is that you have a test service file that is somehow trying to autowire stuff under vendor.  Can you post the relevant portion of BaseTestCase.php?  It's a bit mysterious.

Answer (score 1):

The autowiring cannot guess what is the type of $translator.
You must specify the type of the $translator:

```
    /**
     * Creates a new context factory.
     *
     * @param TranslatorInterface $translator        The translator
     * @param string|null         $translationDomain The translation domain to
     *                                               use for translating
     *                                               violation messages
     */
    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator, string $translationDomain = null)
    {
        if (!$translator instanceof LegacyTranslatorInterface && !$translator instanceof TranslatorInterface) {
            throw new \TypeError(sprintf('Argument 1 passed to "%s()" must be an instance of "%s", "%s" given.', __METHOD__, TranslatorInterface::class, \is_object($translator) ? \get_class($translator) : \gettype($translator)));
        }

        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->translationDomain = $translationDomain;
    }
```

```
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
```

Comment: Indeed, you have to use dependency injection as Florent answer

Comment: I cannot edit this file as its an file from the symfony framework itself.